# discord.js v12 give role1 to message author above last message if last message author has role1

Tags: discord.js

I want to have a role that acts as a disease which will be given to people whos messages are above a message if the message author has the disease role, I've tried searching about the error online but could not get results to work with my code.
(node:13404) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

```
client.on('message', message =>{ 
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.guild.id == 'guildid'){
        getrole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('roleid');
        rolecheck = message.member.roles.cache.has('roleid')
    message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 2 }).then(messages => {
        messageAbove = messages.array(2)['1'].author.id
        if(message.author.id != messageAbove)
        if(rolecheck)
        console.log(messageAbove)
        convertIdToMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(messageAbove)
        message.guild.member(convertIdToMember).roles.add('roleid')
        console.log(messageAbove)

    })
    }else{
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    }
```

Comment: It's telling you that the object you're trying to access the property `.roles` on (`message.guild.member(convertIdToMember)`) is undefined. This is most likely because `message.guild.member` is not a function; note its absence [in the Discord.js documentation for the `Guild` class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild)

Comment: thats strange, i've used message.guild.member with message.mentions.users.first() and it worked fine, using message.guild.members.cache.get appears to yield the same result

Comment: You've already gotten the member from the cache on the line right above that defines `convertIdToMember`. Why not use its `.roles` property instead?

Comment: oh whoops, too much debugging and changing up little things distracted me from realizing that unnecessary line. after doing some further testing it seems that using message.guild.member(mention) works outside of arrow function but doesnt inside the arrow function, I think the problem is making message.guild.member defined inside of an arrow function, any ideas?